# Cross Thread Operation - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a class that creates a new instance of an already existing form every time "New" is called. I'm implementing this in a Class Library, the class library has a "WndClass" (Class) and a "MainWindow" (Form). The problem is I get the above error whenever I try to close the window by InsWindow.Close

Here's the code:

```
Public Class WndClass
   Public Shared WindowCount As Integer
   Private InsWindow As MainWindow

Public Sub New()
    WindowCount += 1
    InsWindow = New MainWindow
    InsWindow.Show()
End Sub

'.... Some window manipulation functions

Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()
    WindowCount -= 1
    InsWindow.Close()
    InsWindow.Dispose()
    MyBase.Finalize()
End Sub
End Class
```

I'm fairly new to the language so I decided to go experimenting and coding random ideas that come to my mind.

EDIT: I've read up some similar but not necessarily the same problems, and some of them said delegates are what solved the issues, can someone explain how can I use it to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003/cross-thread-operation-not-valid-control-accessed-from-a-thread-other-than-the)?

Comment: By the time `Finalize` is being called, it's far too late for code inside such a method to be talking to other managed objects in a sensible fashion. It's only intended for use in cleaning up unmanaged resources (such as ones allocated via P/Invoke calls). I can't offer any more specific advise unless you can say why you thought `Finalize` was the right place to put this code.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the error, I can only take a shot in the dark...

The fact that you mentioned delegates, I would recommend trying the following:

```
Protected Overrides Sub Finalize()

    If Me.InvokeRequired Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.Finalize))
    Else
        WindowCount -= 1
        InsWindow.Close()
        InsWindow.Dispose()
        MyBase.Finalize()
    End If

End Sub
```

`Delegates` are used when you need to change the thread that the code is running on (ie: you need to get back to the UI thread).

Normally you'd have to create a delegate (ie: `Private Delegate Sub Test(val1 As String, val2 As String, etc..)`) then invoke the delegate while passing it the address of the method you wish to invoke (Note: the variables of the delegate must match the method being called).

If there are no variables being passed to the method, you can invoke the `MethodInvoker` like so `Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf Me.Foo))`...

Keep in mind it's good practice to always check if an invoke is required by checking `Me.InvokeRequired`